# Arranging four subjects and six periods

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Question: How many ways are there to arrange four subjects and six periods in a day if two subjects are taught in two periods and remaining two periods for another two different subject.

Here we can arrange this as 6P4. But I don't understand about the following question part,

"two subjects are taught in two periods and remaining two periods for another two different subject"

Comment: Suppose your subjects are $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$. Two of them, say $A$ and $B$ occupy two periods each for a total of four periods. That leaves two periods, one of which must be for $C$ and the other for $D$.

Comment: So, base on your explanation if I consider the two periods for A as 1 period and also the same for B as 1 period, then I will get the total period as 4. Now, will be the answer 4P4 = 24 ways to arrange that?

Comment: Yes, because then the problem is equivalent to finding the number of ways to seat four persons. This problem is more complicated than that.

Comment: Sorry! what you say "the number of ways to seat 4 persons" I don't understand.

Comment: How many ways can you seat $4$ persons in $4$ chairs?

Comment: oh! Haaha......I got it. Thanks for your help btw.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question wants you to imagine yourself as a teacher who is scheduled to teach 6 periods, 2 periods English, 2 Math, 1 History and 1 Geography

potential schedules could be

EMGHEM     or EEMMGH

- Number of ways to schedule English is $\binom 62$
- for each of these possibilities there are $\binom 42$ways to schedule Math
- for each of the above possibilities there are $\binom 21$ways to schedule Geography
- for each of the above possibilities there are $\binom 11$ways to schedule History

So total # of schedules in 
$$ \binom 62 \binom 42 \binom 21 \binom 11 $$

which is the same as $$\frac{6!}{2!2!}$$